# SwiftUI: List and TabView are getting over-lapped each other

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-picker

In my app, i am trying to display: `SegmentedPicker` on top of the screen, Then `List`, Then a simple button on bottom-right of the screen using `safeAreaInset`, and then a tabBar using `TabView`

My problem is that at bottom of the screen, `List` and `TabView` is getting over-lapped each other. Attached Screenshot at the end

Following is the code for my `TabView`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                FirstView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "pencil")
            }
            
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "pencil.circle.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code for my 1st TabView.

Look's like some issue with my `Picker` which is inside the `VStack`. Because if I remove the `Picker`, I don't have any issue.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var firstViewPicker = ["one", "two", "three"]
    @State private var segmentSelection = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            //MARK: - Picker related stuff
            Picker("", selection: $segmentSelection) {
                ForEach(0..<firstViewPicker.count, id: \.self) { id in
                    Text(firstViewPicker[id])
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .padding()
            
            List {
                ForEach(0..<40, id: \.self) { id in
                    Text("Row Item #\(id)")
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.grouped)                
        }
        .navigationTitle("Home")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, alignment: .trailing) {
            Button(action: {
                print("Tapped")
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
                    .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white, .brown)
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
            })
            .padding()
            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the code for my 2nd TabView

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, 2nd  world!")
    }
}
```

Following is the screenshot where I am getting an over-lapping issue of `List` and `TabView`

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? how can we make this work? Kindly help

**FYI:** I am using macOS 13.3, Xcode 14.3, Simulator 14 Pro Max with iOS 16.4

**FYI:** Just noticed that unable to reproduce on iPhone- 12, iPhone Simulator-14. And can able to reproduce on iPhone Simulator -14 pro, iPhone Simulator-14 pro max

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue. All works well for me,
 on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
 It could be different on older systems.

Comment: I am checking on macOS 13.3, Xcode 14.3, Simulator 14 Pro Max with iOS 16.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because `.tabitem` is getting overlapped by the Navigation stack itself. You have to provide padding there. Tried its working for me. Tested on Xcode 14.3

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationStack {
                FirstView()
            }.padding()
            .tabItem {
                Label("First", systemImage: "pencil")
            }
            
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Second", systemImage: "pencil.circle.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]